# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'something'

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

Trying to do something like:

```
facility = 'LOG_LOCAL7'
syslog.openlog( 'Blah', 0, syslog.facility)
```

But I get:

```
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'facility'
```

I want to be able to set the facility in a variable...

On a side note; in Python, what are the different parts of this statement actually called?

```
syslog.openlog( 'Blah', 0, syslog.LOG_LOCAL7)
```

- syslog
- openlog
- 'Blah'

Is it class, method, attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first part, you need `getattr`:

> Help on built-in function `getattr` in module `__builtin__`:
>
> `getattr(...)`
>       `getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value`
>
> ```
> Get a named attribute from an object; getattr(x, 'y') is equivalent to x.y.
> When a default argument is given, it is returned when the attribute doesn't
> exist; without it, an exception is raised in that case.
> ```

So you, need:

```
syslog.openlog('Blah', 0, getattr(syslog, facility))
```

For the second part of your question, as to the breakdown of the statement itself:

- `syslog` (module)
- `.` ([scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator))
- `openlog` (an attribute of the module, in this case, its a function)
- `'Blah'` (an argument to the function)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use getattr (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
facility = 'LOG_LOCAL7'
syslog.openlog( 'Blah', 0, getattr(syslog, facility))
```